# How to trigger the function after DOM markup is loaded in angular style application except onload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-digest

I need to show a Simple current time with an angular based-application.So have tried a demo.

In the body onload function execute the piece of function.

```
<body onload="startTime()">
function startTime() {

}
```

i don't want in javascript function to execute.
Onload is a javascript predefined function,In angular is there any directive like ngload ? need to write the custom directive for this or

Nginit is behave like similar or can i call the function inside run block means what are the difference from angular run vs javascript onload?

if using ng-init,need an controllor,without controller run block is there to execute the angular function. is there any other options available to show on the Dom loaded.

Comment: @AshBringer, i don't have the controller , just have module inside the module without controller only custom directive works, how ng-init will work ? Without custom directive or run block is there any other options available in angular

Answer (score 2):

Use `ngAfterViewInit` from angular API.

You can use ngAfterViewInit as a life cycle hook by importing it from angular/core.

Typical implementation of it would look like following:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
   public ngAfterViewInit() {
     // Do the logic here
   }
}
```

Ref: https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Comment: This was the only way I was able to get this to work, thank you!  Using length kept returning 0, while a collection was loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular's $window object:

```
$window.onload = function(e) {
  //your magic here
}
```

Comment: is there any angular directive like javascript onload? else use  inject the window service and call onload

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

***Using After View Init***

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
   public ngAfterViewInit() {
     // Do the logic here
   }
}
```

**Method 2**

***Using Router NavigationEnd***

NavigationEND is an event trigger when navigation ends successfully, after the event is unsubscribed the page is full loaded, subscribe and execute the function.

```
import {  Component,  OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {  Router, NavigationEnd,} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(    private router: Router,  ) {  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
      )
      .subscribe((event) => {
        this.siteTrafficData();
      });
  }

  siteTrafficData() {
         // Do the logic here
  }
}
```